# how to put * to execute whole '.gql' files from a folder in scripts of package.json

Tags: node.js

i have used scripts body as
 "scripts": {
        "start_docs":"npm run graphdoc",
        "graphdoc": "graphdoc -s schema/*.gql -f -o ./support/reports/graphdoc;exit 0"
    }
While I  put multiple  '.gql' using * from schema folder,
 then error like 
/Documents/graphql_new/stature-gqdss/node_modules/@2fd/command/lib/command/params.js:104
        throw new Error('Unexpected param: ' + param);
        ^

Error: Unexpected param: schema/basic-profile-schema.gql
    at NoParams.parse (/home/jamsheerali/Documents/graphql_new/stature-gqdss/node_modules/@2fd/command/lib/command/params.js:104:15)